# Excel: Autofill Col2 cell of tableB from Col2 of tableA (if Tab 1 Col 1 matches Tab 2 Col 1)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, auto-form-fill

In Excel, I have one table

```
Say | dire
You | vous
...
```

and another

```
You | toi
Say | dire
...
```

Since *You* in the first table matches *You* in the second one, the value *toi* should automatically become *vous*, that is the second table acquire values from the first one. How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use index-match formulas. These are not as volatile as Vlookup, and don't require anything to be formatted in a particular manner or alphabetized.

Index match is a nested formula - consisting of an index formula which references a match lookup. Assuming that the reference table is at site A1-B5, and the table you want to create is at D1-E5 with a lookup source in row D, this is what the formula should look like in cell E1.

```
=index($B$1:$B$5,Match(D1,$a$1:$a$5,0))
```

As a two-part formula, the way it works is as follows:

The index formula returns the entry for column B that the Match formula looks for

The match formula looks for a result in column A that matches the entry in d1, and returns the row number. the 0 denotes an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `VLOOKUP` to do this. Let's say your first table starts in cell A1, and your second table starts in cell F1. Enter this formula in the second column of your second table, and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP(G1,$A$1:$B$99,2,0)
```